# Child Page Activity not Started after inflating ChildView

Tags: android

I am new to Android.

I want to do iPhone like `SplitView` in Android. I did it using `LayoutInflater`.

The view is coming in my child `LinearLayout` but the activity of that view is not started.

So it just render the view it is not starting activity of that `childview`.

I tried using Intent but it does not give me the parent view it only gives `childview`.

Help me to come out of this.

How can I start activity of the inflating view?

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   super.setContentView(R.layout.ParentActivity); 
   LinearLayout ChildView; ChildView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ChildView); 
   ChildView.removeAllViews(); 
   setContentView(R.layout.ChildActivity); 
}
```

and I also override the `setContentView` Method like

```
 @Override public void setContentView(int id) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     inflater.inflate(id, ChildView);

}
```

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.ParentActivity);

        LinearLayout ChildView;

 ChildView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ChildView);
 ChildView.removeAllViews();

 setContentView(R.layout.ChildActivity);

     }

Comment: check http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/06/tablet-ui-patterns-split-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this with [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ?

Comment: ya i tried using this but i have problem with it so i do it using http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx

Comment: For what I can see on that example, you can't start a new activity to handle only the detail or master views, you need to start a new activity for that, inflating detail and master again. When you create a new Android project on Eclipse you can choose a master-detail template that will setup the basics to get exactly what you need.

Comment: master-detail template support SDK 11 onwards but i my app must supports SDK 8 onwards..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure how your app compiles.

Your layout file starts with an Uppercase letter.
Android complains - " File-based resource names must start with a lowercase letter."

Comment: Sorry, its my writing mistake its start with lowercase.